# Is there a way to modify the strings used for localization in iOS at runtime?

Tags: ios, localization

Is there a way to alter the localization strings after iOS reads them from Localizable.strings, and still maintain the ability use `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key, table, bundle, value, comment)`?  In other words, is it possible to programmatically alter localized strings, say, after receiving an updated set of strings from a server?

This question assumes that Localizable.strings can't be modified because that would require modifying the main NSBundle, which is not allowed after an app is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a new bundle containing your desired strings file and use that bundle instead of `[NSBundle mainBundle]` in `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your `NSLocalizedString` macros to whatever you want:

```
#undef  NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
[MyLocalizationManager localizedStringForKey:key]
```